# SCCM uninstall rule is in conflict with install rule

Tags: deployment, collections, uninstallation, membership, sccm

Application A is originally installed by a deployment targeting a collection (Collection A) that populates based off a query.

I have Device A sitting in an AD Group called 'Uninstall Application A'.

Collection B populates from 'Uninstall Application A' AD Group and has a deployment set to Uninstall Application A from its members (Device A, and some other devices that are also members - Device B, C and D).

Collection B is set to be an exclusion of Collection A so if a device is added to 'Uninstall Application A' AD Group it is effectively removed from Collection A, and added to Collection B, thereby deploying the uninstall of Application A on Device A, B, C and D.

I have checked the deployment monitoring for the uninstallation deployment and I can see that although the membership updates have gone through and Device A, B, C and D are no longer members of Collection A and are now members of Collection B, there is a Conflict on Device A and B, but devices C and D are showing successfully removed.

I have the 'Client Centre for ConfigMgr' application and can connect to Device A and B, and I have attempted to download machine policies, evaluate application deployments, evaluate machine policies, I have even reset policies which as far as I am concerned is a sledge hammer approach.

I have monitored the C:\Windows\CCM\Logs (specifically: AppDiscovery, PolicyAgent, AppIntentEval, and AppEnforce) and can see that new policies are being downloaded, evaluated, and actioned so there is no issue with the agent, but I can't for the life of me understand why SCCM still believes that the device is still conflicting with the installation deployment when it's no longer a member of Collection A (the installation collection) anymore, and effectively only getting the 1 deployment from Collection B (to uninstall the application); I do note that the uninstall deployment uses the same Application A, however it just uses the Uninstall action instead of the Install action for the uninstall deployment.

I have allowed it time to sit and was hoping it would work itself out thinking perhaps it was just a delay in evaluation, but it seems that evaluation has happened, and it's still thinking it's conflicting.
I've performed a membership update on both collections, even though they're showing correctly, and the other two devices C and D have worked, so what can I check or do on these other two devices to get them to play the game?